# Logistic Regression with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression

Is this the correct Estimator for Logistic Regression in TF 1.10?

There used to be a function called: `LogisticRegressor` which is [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LogisticRegressor)

In README.md file it says:

```
LogisticRegressor: Not supported. Instead, use binary_classification_head with a custom model_fn, or with DNNEstimator
```

When I look into documentation in tensorflow.org I see an example on Census [data](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/estimators/linear.ipynb):

"We will train a logistic regression model that, given an individual's information, outputs a number between 0 and 1—this can be interpreted as the probability that the individual has an annual income of over 50,000 dollars."
Which is using:

```
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
    model_dir=tempfile.mkdtemp(), 
    feature_columns=base_columns + crossed_columns,
    optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1))
```

Questions:

1) Is there any sample with Logistic Regression for new TF estimator API.

2) Which one would be a good dataset to do Logistic Regression?